# Exception Handling on UI when tomcat server is stopped

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, exception

I have a scenario where application is up and suddenly backend tomcat server is down for some reason. In this case various components on UI which doesn't work as expected. I just want to handle this scenario on UI side so that when user click any button or do any activity, it pops up some generic error message. Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by UI? you should be more specific. Anyway, since you tagged your question with javascript, just add a handler for 404 status in you ajax calls to show the generic error message.

Comment: @tbc - thanks for your answer. what is the solution for for non-ajax calls ?

Comment: If you are using RMI or JMS, you will get a Marshal Exception, for any case there is a solution. So if you can tell us what type of UI you are using and how you are connecting to tomcat. it would be easier to provide help.

Comment: @tbc -I am using pure html + jquery as a library and using struts2 as a backend framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery for your ajax calls, you can easily handle errors like 
this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'url:[your url]'),
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        // do something on success
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        if(xhr.status==404) {
            alert('your generic error message');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what about non-ajax calls ?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then you are using ajax calls, if you mean $.get / $.post, it's the same as $.ajax( type: 'get' ) / $.ajax(type: 'post'), follow [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for more info

Comment: if i click button and on button click i am submitting the form and navigate to different page. that is not ajax call. How can i handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: @SanketPipariya are you using iframes for your forms? if not, then you're getting a 404 not found page!